# ionic-modal auto close when route changes

Tags: ionic-framework, modal-dialog

So i have created a modal with the [ion-modal](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal) component.

This works fine however when ever i change route the modal stays open meaning that the new site is hidden behind the modal that i stil open.

i have looked over the documentation but i couldnt find anything that allows me to control it.

a hack would be to check for route changes but i don't feel that this is the right way to do it.

So my question is how do i make sure that the modal automatically closes when i change route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Documentation:

You can use dismiss function to dismiss modal before you route to any other page or web.

```
dismiss() {
    // using the injected ModalController this page
    // can "dismiss" itself and optionally pass back data
    this.modalCtrl.dismiss({
      'dismissed': true
    });
  }
```

[Model Dismiss Doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal#dismissing-a-modal)